# Named route helpers vs arrays in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems that there are two equivalent ways to create links; either with "*named route helpers*" or a syntax involving an array.

For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, :admin, book] %>
```

versus

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_path(book) %>
```

So far as I can see in the case of links these produce exactly the same results; however in the case of forms they don't.

This produces an explicit edit form, with the CSS class `edit_book` a submit button labelled "Update Book":

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @book], method: :patch do |f| %>
```

whereas this produces a more generic form with no class name and a button labelled "Save Book":

```
<%= form_for :book, url: admin_book_path(@book), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

So, my question is, **what is the syntactical difference** between these two options, **which is more commonly used**, and **are there any more differences in behaviour** other than those I've noted above?

Answer (score 0):

The difference you pointed out is that you are using `link_to` for one example set, and `form_for` in the other example set. These are two different methods, and are not expected to have the same results.

As for which is more common to use, I would suggest using the named path, IE `admin_book_path`, because it is quite expressive to where it is going, and you can always check `rake routes` in order to get more information about a named route.

Comment: Thanks for replying. However the difference I am asking about is not the difference between `link_to` and `form_for`, but rather the difference between, for example, `[:admin, @book]` and `admin_book_path(@book)`, or between `[:edit, :admin, book]` and `edit_admin_path(book)`. Why do both exist, and how do they differ - both syntactically and functionally?